External Authorization stops .NET Core default identity
I can't seem to make external logins work with the default .NET Core identity management.
I got my individual account logins set in the Program.cs with this:
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<UserInfo.ApplicationUser>
    (options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserInfo.ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<UserInfo.ApplicationUser>>();

So far so good everything works great. I attempted to add external logins and here is where the issues begin:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/LogOff";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    })
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Google:ClientId"] ?? "";
        options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Google:ClientSecret"] ?? "";
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
    })
    .AddFacebook(options =>
    {
        options.AppId = builder.Configuration["Facebook:AppId"] ?? "";
        options.AppSecret = builder.Configuration["Facebook:AppSecret"] ?? "";
    });

With these settings, the external logins work perfectly, but the individual account stops working. When I use the SignInManager to login, I get a success, but I am not authenticated.
If I remove the second block from the code, the individual accounts start working again, but the externals don't.
Can anyone give me points on what I might be missing?
I read that setting the CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme actually breaks the AddDefaultIdentity, so my question is more in the lines of what is the best solution for my situation? Should I build a custom identity management, or can I salvage the default identity along with the external?
